# msgrcv not waiting for a message with a specific message type with errno 22 (EINVAL)

Tags: c++, message-queue, system-calls

I am trying to use the msgsnd and msgrcv system calls in the standard C library and am not getting the expected/desired performance.

My problem is that when I call msgrcv, it is not waiting for a message with the specified mtype (4).

I first send a message with an mtype of 1. The idea is that another process would then receive this message and send an acknowledgement message back with an mtype of 4. From the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/apis/ipcmsgrc.htm), I expect that "if msgtyp is greater than zero, the first message of type msgtyp is received".
I also expect it to wait until a message with message type msgtyp is in the queue. 
From the documentation:

- If the IPC_NOWAIT flag is not set in the msgflg parameter, the calling thread suspends processing until one of the following occurs:

  - A message of the desired type is sent to the message queue.
  - The message queue identifier msqid is removed from the system. When this occurs, the msgrcv() function returns with a return value of -1 and errno set to EIDRM.
  - A signal is delivered to the calling thread. When this occurs, the msgrcv() function returns with a return value of -1 and errno set to EINTR.

My msgrcv function does not wait. I have created a minimal, complete, and verifiable example below.

(Also note that I am not running any other of its companion programs that could be intercepting this message with mtype = 1 and sending back another message with mtype = 4 when testing this program).

```
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int qid = msgget(ftok(".",'u'), IPC_EXCL|IPC_CREAT|0600);
    struct buf {
        long mtype; // required
        int message; // mesg content
    };
    buf msg;
    int size = sizeof(msg)-sizeof(long);

    msg.mtype = 1;
    msgsnd(qid, (struct msgbuf *)&msg, size, 0); // sending
    cout << msg.message << endl;
    //Get acknowledgement from receiverA
    msgrcv(qid, (struct msgbuf *)&msg, size, 4, 0); // read mesg
    cout << msg.message << endl;
}
```

UPDATE:

The msgrcv function is returning an errno value of 22 (EINVAL) which according to the documentation means "The MessageQueueID parameter is not a valid message queue identifier."

So I went ahead and checked what the errno value of my msgget function is. The msgget function returns a value of 17 (EEXIST). Not sure what to do with this but the documentation for msgget(), says "If msgflg specifies both IPC_CREAT and IPC_EXCL and a message queue already exists for key, then msgget() fails with errno set to EEXIST."

Just from messing around with the msgget function, if I change the 2nd parameter, in the ftok function to generate a different identifier, it works but only when I run it once, if I try to run it a second time with the same identifier, the error returns. 
So I guess my question can be simplified to: How can I get the qid of the message queue I want to use but not try to generate it if it already exists?

Comment: Can you print out `errno` value after calling `msgrcv`?

Comment: @MinhHoàng made an update with the relevant errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `IPC_EXCL` from when calling `msgget`.

From `https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node34.html`

> **IPC_EXCL**
>
> When used with **IPC_CREAT**, fail if queue already exists.

Answer (score 1):

From man page:

> If msgflg specifies both IPC_CREAT and IPC_EXCL and a message queue
>          already exists for key, then msgget() fails with errno set to EEXIST.

When I tried to execute your code for the first time it blocked on msgrcv()  but when I re-executed it didn't. Because in next iteration  msgget() failed with EXIST and qid filled with -1. Due to this msgsnd() as well as msgrcv() failed with invalid argument.

Solution to above problem is to remove message queue, use msgctl() to remove message queue id before returning from test program as follows:

> msgctl(qid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

Advise: Always check return value of system calls.

Hope this will help you.